# Unsupported Modules Detected

Tags: android, android-studio, synchronization, android-studio-3.1.3

2nd question in 2 days - not going well.

I am trying to learn how to use Android Studio via Udacity and struggling to get one of their repository's to work from github. They state that we may have a few issues with syncing as it may have been built using an older SDK than what currently exists

here are the trouble shooting steps they have provided if I come into syncing issues

1. Fork this repository to your GitHub account.
2. Open Android Studio.
3. File -> New -> Project from version control - GitHub
4. Paste a link from your repository of the forked Miwok app, push Clone.
5. Agree the presented terms. Update everything that's asked

but once I have cloned the repository it provides me with this sync error:

Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: ud839_Miwok. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.

and also syncing error:
Gradle sync failed: Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle-4.7\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.10-all\a4w5fzrkeut1ox71xslb49gst\gradle-2.10-all.zip.lck

Currently using Android Studio 3.1.3 had trouble ever since the update

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Why does your title include a different error message than your post describes?

Comment: as these are the two errors I am getting, thought they may be linked - changed it now Ken.

Comment: Try "File -> Sync Project with Gradle files" and if that does not help use "File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart".